# Draw a shadow using CoreGraphics manually?

Tags: iphone, c, core-graphics

How can I draw a shadow like the one you'd get with **CGContextSetShadowWithColor** but manually? I basically need to draw the path and then somehow blur it, so what I'm really asking is how to blur a shape drawn with CG so it looks like a shadow.

I need to draw it manually. Please don't ask "Why not just use the function?".

Comment: @Dhaivat Pandya, the added tag "objective-c" was unnecessary. CoreGraphics is a C framework.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option if you are on the Mac is to use [Core Image](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html) which provides a several blur filters. Another more difficult option would be to draw into your own buffer and then run your own [Gaussian Blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) on it.